Why is the R squared scored negative for for my validation data after training it with a CNN?
I am trying to perform non-linear fitting using a convolutional network. The curves I would like to perform the fitting on look like this:

So, I've organized my data to be a Numpy array in which every row is a curve. Each row has 512 data points (columns) which correspond to the curve, plus two additional columns (513 and 514) that contained the targets. The targets are the two fitting parameters I would like the CNN to generate. There are 19889 rows (curves) in my training dataset.
# We assign the features and the outputs.
X = df_array[:,1:-2]
y = df_array[:,-2:]


My model is built using keras and it looks like this:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, 
activation='relu',data_format="channels_last", input_shape=(512,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))

The compilation and fit lines look like this
# We compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer= Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['mean_squared_error', 'mean_absolute_error','r2_score','root_mean_squared_error'])

# We define the callbacks.
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 25, verbose=2)
log_csv = CSVLogger('Model_2_IRF_extraction_lr00005.csv', separator= ',', append=False)
callbacks_list = [early_stop, log_csv]

# We fit the keras model on the dataset.
history = model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.1, epochs=500, batch_size=10, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks_list)

The fitting runs, but my Rsquare values for the validation set and my validation loss look really weird. Please see below.


What is wrong with my CNN? I suspect it has something to do with the "input_shape" parameter in the first layer, but I can't figure out what to do.

Are you sure you really are fitting on 90% of your dataset? Basically after the first few epochs you are overfitted (you get perfect R2, and your loss is also on log scale).
Could you update your question with the code you use to define  x and y?
Or simply with the whole code you have?

Hi. Yes I'm sure I'm fitting on 90% of my dataset because I have used the same code for fully connected layers and it works perfectly well. I can't add all the code because I need to keep some things confidential. I will add the code needed to define x and y. Thanks.

X = df_array[:,1:-2]
y = df_array[:,-2:]
If your df_array is shaped (N, 514), then this code creates an (N, 511) shaped X array, but that should make your training fail, so I assume this was only a typo.
Otherwise I managed to train exactly the same network on dummy data and it worked perfectly. So maybe your data is corrupted or just very weird.

Also, your R2 and other loss is still increasing (decreasing), are your results actually bad? I know this does not answer the question, but if in the end the model performs acceptable, then this is just a weird training curve. I was wrong when I said "overfitting", since you model still gets better and better on the val set, it's just very weird that it instantly performs perfectly on the train set.

Note that negative R2 doesn’t necessarily mean your model is entirely flawed; it highlights areas for improvement.
